# Got an error when get the access token for GHL integrations

Tags: postman

I am using GHL with my development. For when first time, I could create a contact and then I moved on to create a conversation. Then 400 errors were raised and could not create the access token in postman. Attachments are given below

[This issue is raised when try to get an access token from the postman collection.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVEmQ.png)

[This issue also raised when access token from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQnDL.png)

I tried refresh the GHL account and double check the Client ID and client secret as well. But there are no issues.